# Can I made Firebase as a webservice

Tags: firebase, web-services, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make a website which the database using firebase realtime database. Then when i made the system architecture. How should i make? Is it like this?
Web - web services(Firebase) - realtime db

Answer (score 0):

I typically have my web application (JavaScript) code talk directly to Firebase. To secure access to the data, I sign the users in with [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth) either with credentials or [anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth). Once that is done, you can use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to ensure users can only access data they're authorized for.

To learn more about this, I recommend taking the Firebase [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) or take one of the many tutorials that are out there showing you how to get started with Firebase in a web app.